# XD Proxy hangs on Facebook Connect login

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have recently come across the same hanging ‘XD Proxy’ in all browsers when attempting to login through a public site via Facebook Connect and only experienced this the day before yesterday.

When attempting to login normally via Facebook Connect button via the 'Log In' button, we encounter the hanging dialog popup at the address bar.

The url at the address bar of the XD Proxy popup is follows:

https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/xd_proxy.php?version=3#cb=feac6ba71b83ac&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Ff29dcc19c684c1c&relation=opener&transport=postmessage&frame=f366e3c5d4f85d2&access_token=AAAAAQXuZAol4BAFcZBEZBPNw1qFN7liSfzgd8brqPstvo1yFiVbG4xymW9CEIohr6vczV20CK27xEP6JUYOObgZCLzxWPDKoxbtvi4vSdnYMr8QZAc4P2&expires_in=6819&signed_request=4i2nufVfL0dZkQS0K8gbPeKfT5LOviSk89Kpaxunfs4.eyJhbGdvcml0aG0iOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1NiIsImNvZGUiOiJBUUJvUzBHaHVlVEhmNWMzTEd5bW9TT21jSlYtblJ4eEViX3Q5WjlWTDVCZDBCMk4tZThYeG9lZ2VwUDJGQ3JnTFZZS0FINU1wSUY5cTVLNEFkR0JHMmpjNFdLVW80OHEwbG5ITG83eE9LaGM1M0tic0lXd2VsVFU5Mkhzejh1V2dxOFRRTjA4YVhpRVdfTFRsQ29oZFpfU090MnVWY3l3Zzh2LTQ1c0lwSHVkdC1SSENEc3hmeWtISm9feWMtNUNaNmciLCJpc3N1ZWRfYXQiOjEzMjkyODk1ODEsInVzZXJfaWQiOiIxNjgyNjI3MjU3In0

The following is a code snippet is my 'Init' code:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: ConfigAppID, // App ID
                channelURL: '//exampleurl/channel.html', // Channel File (note I have not put http: or https: here as this was suggested by a user on the facebook bug forum pertaining to this issue
                status: true, // check login status
                cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                oauth: true, // enable OAuth 2.0
                xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
            });

            // Additional initialization code here
        };

        // Load the SDK Asynchronously
        (function (d) {
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
            js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js";
            d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
        } (document));

    });
```

My auth code snippet is a follows:

```
 <input type="image" src="assets/images/btn_enter.gif" class="button" value="Enter Competition" onclick="fb_authorise()" />
```

Definition of fb_authorise() is as follows:

```
function fb_authorise() {

    FB.login(function (response) {

        if (response.authResponse) {

            console.log('fb_authorise() - authorsied ');
            window.top.location.href = 'www.facebook.com/pages/exampleTestPage/171655142343955?sk=app_242716140284588';

        } else {
            console.log('fb_authorise() - not authorsied');
        }

    }, { scope: 'email' });

    return false;
}
```

I can 100 percent confirm my code has no hacks or workarounds (this code was always working until about 2 days ago)

After applying the code snippet above, I cleared my browser cache to ensure that all resource is reloaded by the browser (a suggestion by a facebook user on the facebook bug forum), however I am still getting the hanging dialog.

We are experiencing this issue (hanging popup) on all browsers.

Has anyone found a solution for this? I know there is already a support person at Facebook looking into the issue as of 9 February 2012. But any earlier suggestions of a permanent fix is welcomed as we require an urgent fix!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that happened to me once and I took out the channelUrl and it fixed it

Comment: Hi Alex, I have tried removing the channel url but that didn't work for me. There were other suggestions to ensure that we use window.fbAsyncInit. That too didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found that resetting Chrome worked for me. Found the solution here.
http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=310bc994b12d2750&hl=en&fid=310bc994b12d27500004b99649c0e573

- Removed all extensions: Tools > Extensions
- Removed all apps: Open new tab > Apps. Right click and remove
- Restarted Chrome

The XD Proxy window no longer hangs in my application.

Been trying to find a solution for 2 days.  Glad that worked.